# call php class function again with new parameter

Tags: class

i have a problem when i call function

> $categ->categ_body()

for second time the parameter does not change

```
$categ = new Categories("Autos & Vehicles"); 

$categ->categ_body(60*60*24);
$adm_json_arr["a_v_num_last_24_h_videos"] = $categ->body_vid_num;

// last 7 days
$categ->categ_body(60*60*24*7);
$adm_json_arr["a_v_num_last_7_d_videos"] = $categ->body_vid_num;
```

do i need to do something so when i call the function the parameter to change or i must call the class again

```
function categ_body($time){
        require $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . '/include/database/connect_cnt.php';
        $time2 = time() - ($time *2);
        $this->time = $time;
        $time = time() - $time;

        $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT COUNT(Id) AS Id_count FROM video WHERE Category = '" .$this->categ. 
                               "' AND Published = '1' AND Date > '" .$time. "'");

        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();
        $stmt->bind_result($ctg_last_videos);
        $stmt->fetch();

        $this->body_vid_num = number_format($ctg_last_videos);
 }
```

all the problem is with the parameter of $time which stays

> 60*60*24

and does not change to

> 60*60*24*7

Comment: Please edit your post and include the code for the Categories class. We can't help if we don't know what code is inside `categ_body()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have something like a getter and a setter:

```
class Categories{
 public $body_vid_num;

 public function setBodyVidNum($num){
   // some process or logic
   ...
   $this->body_vid_num = $some_value;
 }

 public function getBodyVidNum(){
   return $this->body_vid_num;
 }

}
```

then use it like:

```
$categ->setBodyVidNum(60*60*24);
$adm_json_arr["a_v_num_last_24_h_videos"] = $categ->getBodyVidNum();

// last 7 days
$categ->setBodyVidNum(60*60*24*7);
$adm_json_arr["a_v_num_last_7_d_videos"] = $categ->getBodyVidNum();
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd start by changing the categ_body() function to receive a mysql DATE_SUB interval text as opposed to the number of seconds. Then, I would modify the query to utilize this. Then, to make it just one call, I'd then return the value I assigned to the class variable.

```
function categ_body($time = '24 HOUR'){
    require $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . '/include/database/connect_cnt.php';

    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT COUNT(Id) AS Id_count FROM video WHERE Category = '" .$this->categ.
    "' AND Published = '1' AND Date > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL {$time}))");

    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    $stmt->bind_result($ctg_last_videos);
    $stmt->fetch();

    $this->body_vid_num = number_format($ctg_last_videos);
    return number_format($ctg_last_videos);
}
```

Now, you just call the function once and pass in the correct parameter:

```
// No need to pass in a param here, since we set the default value of time
// to '24 HOUR'
$adm_json_arr["a_v_num_last_24_h_videos"] = $categ->setBodyVidNum();
$adm_json_arr["a_v_num_last_7_d_videos"] = $categ->setBodyVidNum('7 DAY');
```

It's not a normal thing to do, to return a value from a setter, but it's not entirely a bad thing. If you feel like you'd rather go with conventional style you could always just do:

```
// No need to pass in a param here, since we set the default value of time
// to '24 HOUR'
$categ->setBodyVidNum();
$adm_json_arr["a_v_num_last_24_h_videos"] = $categ->getBodyVidNum();

$categ->setBodyVidNum('7 DAY');
$adm_json_arr["a_v_num_last_7_d_videos"] = $categ->getBodyVidNum();
```

Answer (score 0):

What are you doing inside categ_body() function?

You will need to set the body_vid_num within that function.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
$adm_json_arr["a_v_num_last_24_h_videos"] = $categ->categ_body(60*60*24);
$adm_json_arr["a_v_num_last_7_d_videos"] = $categ->categ_body(60*60*24*7);
```